# maven package error: SurefireReportParameters

Tags: java, spring, maven, oauth

i try to package my maven package but i got this error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test': Unable to load the mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefireReportParameters
org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireReportParameters
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test': Unable to load the mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefireReportParameters
```

Hier is a part of my pom.xml with all the dependencies and plugins:

```
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rest-service-oauth</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.0.7.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

when i call this command mvn -e clean package, i got the error above.

I try to test this oauth2-project. The link:

https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth

i cloned the project und i try to test it. But i have this error by package.

Any ideas?

Thank
Cheers

Comment: Version `2.18.1` in your POM and `2.17` in the error message makes me wonder.

Comment: Me too. I try to remove the 2.17-Version but maven install it again and not the 2.18.1.

Comment: I seems that one of your other dependencies uses 2.17 as transitive dependency. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023646/maven-transitive-dependencies-with-different-versions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979893/maven-same-transitive-dependency-but-different-version and [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).